# When I scroll to the top of a page, my mouse scrolls down slightly

Tags: windows-7, mouse, scrolling, logitech-mouse

Okay, so when I scroll to the top of a webpage in Firefox, or anywhere in my Windows 7 PC, weather it be settings or a browser, the wheel sensitivity is way too high, like one little scroll on the wheel moves halfway down the page, and when I scroll to the top of anything, it scrolls down a little bit, and I can't view the top of this page. This however does not occur when I go to the bottom of my page. I have a Logitech Wireless VX mouse.

Please help me, this is really driving me nuts!

Mouse software I have:
Logitech Gaming Software
SetPoint
IntelliPoint

Recent stuff I put onto my rig just before this started:
S.T.R.I.K.E. 7 Keyboard by Madcatz, installed it's drivers and software.

Answer (score 0):

### Windows Setting (try first)

I'd start with the easy one first and check to see if the `Vertical Scrolling` is too high in Windows.

1. [Open `Mouse` in `Control Panel`](http://www.wikihow.com/Adjust-a-Mouse-in-Windows-7)
2. Select the `Wheel` tab
3. If the Vertical Scrolling is much higher than 3 - 5, it's likely too high.

**EDIT**

### Logitech SetPoint Smooth Scrolling (Try second)

Do you have a SetPoint plugin in your browser?  If so, it may be a result of the `Smooth Scrolling` setting in SetPoint.

Disable Smooth Scrolling in SetPoint:

> 1. Launch SetPoint by clicking the SetPoint icon SetPoint Icon in the Notification area and select Mouse and Keyboard Settings.
> 2. Click on Pointer Settings, and clear Enable Smooth Scrolling.
>      [image]
> 3. Click Apply and then OK to exit the SetPoint User Interface.
>
> [Source](http://www.wikihow.com/Adjust-a-Mouse-in-Windows-7)

Please report back and let me know if that helps.

Comment: I already Looked through every setting possible on Windows, and I uninstalled all my logitech software and mouse software listed. Still, no difference. I just connected a differend wired logitech mouse but now it works better.

Comment: With a wired mouse it works, with my wireless mouse it doesn't. The wired has the normal scroll any old mouse has and the new one has one of those 2 options of scrolling (the click and the smooth scroll)

Comment: Try turning off `Smooth Scrolling`.  I just updated the answer with a article I found (see Source link), indicating `Smooth Scrolling` has been an issue for some.  You may want to disable any `SetPoint` add-in in your browser as well (the article explains where to find it), if one exists.